# Is it possible to simulate bump maps using lighting?

Tags: lighting

Like, when there is a dent in some object, the dented part will be less illuminated by light. When there is a bump in an object,  the lower rims of the bump will cast small shadows and the upper part will be more affected by light. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

Well here's the funny thing,

Bump mapping already creates the illusion of detail using lighting tricks. No actual detail is created.
For example:
[image]

In this quick little render, I only used a bump map.

As you can see, no real detail is created but blender is using lighting tricks to give an illusion of depth by casting shadows and bouncing extra light. So I think bump mapping already does what you asked for.

BLEND FILE: https://pasteall.org/blend/e18270574ea0464cb27904593c648695

Comment: This is exactly correct but is there a way to do it without the bump node ? Only using lights ?

Comment: Maybe you can but that's gonna be counter-intuitive. I personally don't know of a method to do that